# How to disable a button that adds new text inputs, to prevent user from keep adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is a piece of code within my system that allows the user to press a button within the class "addtextbox" which then inserts a new text box. This function is used so that the user can add more pieces of information on the page, however, I only want it to last for 4 times, preventing the over use and stopping the user adding too many new text boxes.

```
 $(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         $(".addtextbox").before("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using flagging variable, try this below code :

```
  $(function() {
   // set default value
   // at initial state
   var limit = 1;
   $(".addtextbox").click(function() { 
     // if already added 4 times        
     if ( limit === 4 ) {
        // disabling button from click
        $(".addtextbox").prop('disabled', true);
        //return;
     } 

     $(".addtextbox").before("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");  
     // increase value + 1      
     limit++;

   });
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/hmb8xwyx/)

Comment: I think, there is no need of the `return;`, code after that is never executed if the `if` part executes, as inside an `else`, does it have some advantage? btw, +1 for the flag variable solution

Comment: Nice advice there. Thanks mate.

Comment: you welcome, and who has downvoted you? and didn't feel the need for giving reasons?

Answer (score 0):

As you are appending the inputs before the button you can use http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

```js
$(".addtextbox").click(function() {
  var $button = $(this);

  if ($button.prevAll(".options").length < 4) {
    $button.before("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");
  } 
  else {
    $button.prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addtextbox">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can decrease from limit.

Also, you 
can replace from `$(".addtextbox")` to `$(this)` inside of click function: http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/wrptgmcd/1/

```
   var limit = 4;//it is limited value
   $(".addtextbox").click(function() { 

       $(this).before("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");  
       limit--;

       if ( limit <= 0 ) {
          $(this).prop('disabled', true);
       } 

   });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this:

```
$(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         var counter = $(this).data('counter');
         if (counter <= 4) {
             $(".addtextbox").before("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");
             $(this).data('counter', counter++);
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: The DOM is not a datastore, don't use it as such.

Answer (score -1):

you can do so by appending the input boxes in a div like something -

```
<div id="infobox"></div>
```

and then check each time, its child elements with input tag name counts to four or not?

```
if($('#infobox > input').length != 4) {
...
}
```

Full code will be -

```
<div id="infobox"></div>
<button class="addtextbox">Add more info</button>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         if($('#infobox > input').length != 4) {
             $('#infobox').append("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");
             if($('#infobox > input').length == 4) {
                 $(".addtextbox").attr('disabled', true);
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLpmwmg0/1/)

Comment: it is not faster. it always address to $('#infobox > input').length

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev it don't addresses each milliseconds, just only when the `button` is clicked.. so the performance drop would be negligible of negligible??

Comment: it seems that I've got an enemy here, who is just downvoting my posts without giving reasons for doing so, (might be jealous of me) :)

Answer (score -1):

This is simple task, but I recommend you to learn about loadsh.com
It have many helper function that can help you, in this kind of tasks.

```
 $(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(_.before(4,function() {
         $(".addtextbox").before("<input [type='text'] class='options' placeholder='Enter Text Here'><br>");
     }));
 });
```

_.before quote from: https://lodash.com/docs#before

> Creates a function that invokes func, with the this binding and
>   arguments of the created function, while it’s called less than n
>   times. Subsequent calls to the created function return the result of
>   the last func invocation.